# Kiu estas Liza en la kanto de Persone kaj kial ŝi pentras bildojn?

Tags: culture

"Liza pentras bildojn". Eble preskaŭ ĉiu konas [la faman kanton  de Persone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rzLDRnEUNQ). Sed mi ne tiel bone komprenas [la tekston](http://bertilow.com/persone/tekstoj/liza_pentras_bildojn.html) de ĝi. Ĉu iu scias:

- Kiu estas Liza?
- Kial ŝi pentras bildojn?
- Kial la kantisto ne plu pentras?
- Pri kio temas la kanto ĝenerale?

Comment: Nu, evidente ŝi ĉiam volis pentri bildojn, do tial ŝi pentris ilin... :P

Comment: Sed ne ĉiam, ĉar iam ŝia farbskatol’ perdiĝis kun la vol’. :p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mi fakte scias, kiu estas Liza. Mi eĉ renkontis ŝin plurfoje. Sed mi ne povas doni pli da detaloj pri ŝia identeco.

Ŝi pentras bildojn, ĉar ŝi estas artistino.

La kantisto transiris al aliaj artoformoj.

Pri la cetera temo prefere ĉiu aŭskultanto elpensu sian propran klarigon.

Comment: Ĉu vi estis la kantisto de la bando kaj verkisto de PMEG? Ŭaŭ, verŝajne neniu povus pli bone respondi! Estas granda honoro por vi ke vi donis respondon por mia demando.

Comment: Kompreneble granda honoro por MI :-) Ne eblas redakti tion :-)